# Listen to 433MHz signals in the background

Tags: boot, signal

How can I listen for 433MHz signals in the backgrounds from boot on?

I am using this receiver / transmitter pair [here](http://www.ebay.com/itm/5pcs-433Mhz-RF-transmitter-and-receiver-kit-for-Arduino-/251673838721?hash=item3a98ee0481).

An Arduino sends signals to the Raspberry Pi and I want to listen for them in the background. I tried the examples included in [433Utils](https://github.com/ninjablocks/433Utils) but they use the CPU to like 98% and that's not an option. Are there any other ways?

Comment: What signals are being sent and how often?  Are the messages formatted with any protocol?

Comment: I honestly don't know. I send messages from the arduino using the VirtualWire library, which handles that for me. Also I plan to send some short strings

Answer (score 2):

There is a Virtual Wire module in the [Python examples](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Python_code) for my [pigpio](http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/index.html) library.

Have a look and see if it can read your Arduino messages.

It should use a lot less than 98% CPU.

If it still uses too much I did do a quick port to C which uses a lot less CPU but I have not bothered to post that to the examples.

---

EDITED TO ADD

This [raspberry Pi forum post](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?p=682408#p682408) gives an indication of the performance you may get with C rather than Python.  It also gives the code I used.

It's static which is the real killer.  The software has to process and discard all the false edges while waiting for a real message.  With Python this might take 50%+ of CPU, with the C implementation it seemed to take 10%.

Comment: I will definitely check that out, thanks! I do not own an arduino yet, but wanted to make sure I can start as soon as I get it without having to google for problems :) I will report back asap!

Comment: Would you be able to give me an average estimation of how much cpu it would use without C and using C?

Comment: @qwertz I added some information to the post.

Comment: Thank you very much! 10% seems to be perfect, I can luve with that number just fine I hope. I will try is asap when I get the receiver :)

Comment: So I got my parts now, but do not have any idea of how to use your code. Could you provide some info about that?